# JavaScript can't count element inside a div element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a Chrome extension, which can sort the videos of a website. For example, I search for a word `stackoverflow' and many videos appear there, but these videos do not have the number of comments displayed in the search result, you have to open this video and get the number of comments. And this is my problem, I actually managed to do something similar, I can get the number of comments but it's not working properly

[UPDATED CODE]

```
function waitForElm(selector) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
          }
      
          const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
              resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
              observer.disconnect();
            }
          });
      
          observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
          });
        });
      }
      
      function simulateMouseClick(element) {
        // Send mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, click, mouseout
        const eventNames = [
          'mouseover',
          'mouseenter',
          'mousedown',
          'mouseup',
          'click',
          'mouseout',
        ];
        eventNames.forEach((eventName) => {
          const detail = eventName === 'mouseover' ? 0 : 1;
          const event = new MouseEvent(eventName, {
            detail: detail,
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
          });
          element.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
      }
      
      const openAndPrintVideoContent = async (videoTriggerElement) => {
        try {
          simulateMouseClick(videoTriggerElement);
      
          const commentCountElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-comment-count"]');
          console.log("Comment Element Count:" +commentCountElement.textContent)
          const browserCloseElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-close"]');
      
          simulateMouseClick(browserCloseElement);
      
          return commentCountElement.textContent;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('ERROR: '+error);
          return 0;
        }
      };
      
      const getVideoList = async () => {
        const videos = document.querySelectorAll(".tiktok-18e9va3-DivContainer");
        // console.log(videos)
        return videos;
      };
      
      const hydrateVideoList = async () => {
        const videos = await getVideoList();
        const resources = [];
      
        for (const video of videos) {
          const videoInformation = await openAndPrintVideoContent(video);
          resources.push(videoInformation);
        }
      
        return resources;
      };
      
      hydrateVideoList().then((videoComments) => {
        console.log('Video Comments:', videoComments);
      });
```

This code returns the number of comments, but it also changes the URL in Chrome, and then takes me away from the page where I'm sorting, is there any other way I can do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the code is working you can customized it to your needs

remove console logs and the wrapping functions if you want and add a scroll down function to load +100 videos and apply sorting

```
(function () {
  class Video {
    link;
    title;
    comments;
    element;
    constructor(link, title, comments, element) {
      this.link = link;
      this.title = title;
      this.comments = comments;
      this.element = element;
    }
  }

  function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
        return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
      }

      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
          resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
          observer.disconnect();
        }
      });

      observer.observe(document.body, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
      });
    });
  }

  function simulateMouseClick(element) {
    // Send mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, click, mouseout
    const eventNames = [
      "mouseover",
      "mouseenter",
      "mousedown",
      "mouseup",
      "click",
      "mouseout",
    ];
    eventNames.forEach((eventName) => {
      const detail = eventName === "mouseover" ? 0 : 1;
      const event = new MouseEvent(eventName, {
        detail: detail,
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      });
      element.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
  }

  const getVideoInformations = async (videoTriggerElement) => {
    try {
      console.log("getVideoInformations");
      console.log(videoTriggerElement);

      simulateMouseClick(
        videoTriggerElement.querySelector('a')
      );
      console.log("getVideoInformations");
      console.log(videoTriggerElement);

      const commentCountElement = await waitForElm(
        '[data-e2e="browse-comment-count"]'
      );

      const descElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-video-desc"]');

      const linkElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-video-link"]');
      const video = new Video(
        linkElement.textContent,
        descElement.children[0].textContent,
        commentCountElement.textContent,
        videoTriggerElement
      );

      // const browserCloseElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-close"]');

      //simulateMouseClick(browserCloseElement);
      history.back();

      // wait to go back to the video list
      await waitForElm('[data-e2e="search_top-item-list"]');

      return video;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + error);
      return;
    }
  };

  const getVideoElementList = async () => {
    const videos = document.querySelectorAll(
      ".tiktok-1soki6-DivItemContainerForSearch"
    );
    console.log("getVideoElementList");
    console.log(videos);
    return videos;
  };

  const hydrateVideoElementList = async (videos) => {
    const resources = [];

    for (const video of videos) {
      if (video) {
        const videoInformation = await getVideoInformations(video);
        resources.push(videoInformation);
      }
    }

    return resources;
  };
  const showSortingElements = (resources) => {
    for (const resource of resources) {
      resource.element.setAttribute("data-order", resource.comments);
    }

    SortData();
  };

  function comparator(a, b) {
    if (a.dataset.order < b.dataset.order) return -1;
    if (a.dataset.order > b.dataset.order) return 1;
    return 0;
  }

  // Function to sort Data
  function SortData() {
    var subjects = document.querySelectorAll("[data-order]");
    var subjectsArray = Array.from(subjects);
    let sorted = subjectsArray.sort(comparator);
    sorted.forEach((e) =>
      document.querySelector('[data-e2e="search_top-item-list"]').appendChild(e)
    );
  }

  (async () => {
    const videos = await getVideoElementList();

    const resources = await hydrateVideoElementList(videos);

    // sorting array of object by property
    resources.sort((a, b) => (a.comments > b.comments ? 1 : -1));
    console.log(resources);

    showSortingElements(resources);
  })();
})();
```

screenshots

original videos

[image: original videos]

Ordred videos

[image: Ordred videos]

Comment: This code seems to work both from your screenshot example and from the way it shows things in the console.log, but it's doing something strange to me. After sorting the videos or something similar, he opens another blank tab and in the current tab where the tiktok search videos are, he opens a single video and stays there

Comment: Also the video is sorteb by random , not any order asc or desc

Comment: @Maison012 the code work well i tested it by injecting him with run-javascript (extension) perhaps the bug come from your extension background service you need also to exchange message between the background service and the content scripts for example the background service open new tab and **wait until page are loaded** then he send **message** to the content scripts to sort the videos and when content scripts finish he send **response** to the background who is waiting this response to start new search...

Comment: I just have added `// const browserCloseElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-close"]');

      //simulateMouseClick(browserCloseElement);` this  function after `showSortingElements(resources);` this function and it work for me, i should costumize it as my need couse i still have something to edit, for example when i do sorting first time and if i click outside popup then when open popup again it do sorting again

Answer (score 1):

for this issue :

```
'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.
```

you can use await key only in async function or top levels of modules

index.js

```
console.log('Hello await at top levels of modules')
await Promise.resolve(console.log('the code run without issue'));

console.log('Hello await in async functions')
const hello = >>>>> async <<<<< () => {
    await Promise.resolve(console.log('the code run without issue'));
}
```

i change the openAndPrintVideoContent to return only the video comment number to show you how to wait for elements

for the rest of the code you can create getVideoList() function that return an array of videos from the index of tiktok then you create function hydrateVideoList() to collect video information using openAndPrintVideoContent()

```
const getVideoList = async () => {

   /// here you can create another function like wait element but this time to wait many elements 
   const videos = document.querySelectorAll('[data-e2e="feed-video"]');

   return videos;
}


hydrateVideoList = async () => {
   const videos = await getVideoList();

   const resources = []; // or you can use new Map()
   for (const video of videos) {
      const videoInformation = await openAndPrintVideoContent(video);
      resources.push(videoInformation);
   }

   return resources;
}

const openAndPrintVideoContent = async (videoTriggerElement ) => {

    try {
                
        simulateMouseClick(videoTriggerElement)

        const commentCountElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-comment-count"]');
            
        

        const browserCloseElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-close"]');
            
        simulateMouseClick(browserCloseElement)

        return commentCountElement.textContent;
    }
    catch (error) {
        return 0;
    }
}
hydrateVideoList();
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. This code really helps me a lot, now i can get the number of comment foreach video. The `[UPDATED CODE]` is how my code looks like also. But i still have a questions. The main point of this function is to make sorting of the videos. On the first questions i was showing a function i use for sorting but now all my logic has changed. Any idea how to make video sorting from larges to lowest number of comments?

Comment: Also i have a small problem with this code. It return me this array `Video Comments: (12) ['8609', '75', '242', '1148', '281', '14', '586', '623', '87', '2457', '1018', '47']` but after the function is done it show me a single video , so iam not anymore on the search results but on the single video content.  I need to stay on the search results so i also can make sorting works

Answer (score 0):

use mutator to wait until element exists this way ou can be sure that the comments are loaded after

```
videoTriggerElement.click(); // Open Video
```

when the element is present you can get the comments count safely

example of mutator to wait until element exists :

```
function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}
```

To use it:

```
waitForElm('.some-class').then((elm) => {
    console.log('Element is ready');
    console.log(elm.textContent);
});
```

you can also find other functions that use timeout if the comments page are not loaded proprely

```
async function waitForElement(selector, timeout = null, location = document.body) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let element = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (element) {
            return resolve(element);
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(async () => {
            let element = document.querySelector(selector);
            if (element) {
                resolve(element);
                observer.disconnect();
            } else {
                if (timeout) {
                    async function timeOver() {
                        return new Promise((resolve) => {
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                observer.disconnect();
                                resolve(false);
                            }, timeout);
                        });
                    }
                    resolve(await timeOver());
                }
            }
        });

        observer.observe(location, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
        });
    });
}
```

usage

```
await waitForElement(".nav-alt", 500, ".main-body")
```

Comment: Thanks, for helping. Based on your code i have made an `[UPDATED-2]` version for mine. But i get undefinded value `[mutation.target:[object MutationRecord]
                 CommentCountElement: undefined]`

Comment: I  just make some changes, this is who my code looks like lastly. But still this is not working as i except. Can you help me with this . I really have stuck here

Comment: @Maison012 try to use this library @testing-library/user-event or Cypress to simulate click on elements because element.click()  doesnt work on react website and tell me if it work (try Cypress  first)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it look working for me but you need to rework this code to be most performant because if it is for commercial use you need to add a reject to your promise when waiting for element and if it is not found (caused by network failure...) you can set comment count to 0 or reschedule the url

[image: Tittok comment count]

```
function waitForElm(selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
      return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
        resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });
  });
}

function simulateMouseClick(element) {
  // Send mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, click, mouseout
  const eventNames = [
    'mouseover',
    'mouseenter',
    'mousedown',
    'mouseup',
    'click',
    'mouseout',
  ];
  eventNames.forEach((eventName) => {
    const detail = eventName === 'mouseover' ? 0 : 1;
    const event = new MouseEvent(eventName, {
      detail: detail,
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    });
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  });

}


const openAndPrintVideoContent = async (selector) => {

    try {
    
        const videoTriggerElement = document.querySelector(selector);
            
        simulateMouseClick(videoTriggerElement)

        const commentCountElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-comment-count"]');
            
        alert(commentCountElement.textContent);

        const browserCloseElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-close"]');
            
        simulateMouseClick(browserCloseElement)
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

openAndPrintVideoContent(".tiktok-9oopl7-DivVideoCardContainer")
```

wait for element with reject

```
const waitForElement = (selector, opts) => {
  let timeout = undefined;
  let root = undefined;

  if (opts) {
    ({ root, timeout } = opts);
  }

  if (root === undefined) root = document.body;
  
  const nodeFound = root.querySelector(selector);
  if (nodeFound) return new Promise(resolve => resolve(nodeFound));

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let callback = () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };

    const _resolve = (node) => {
      callback();
      resolve(node);
    };

    const _reject = (err) => {
      callback();
      reject(err);
    };

    if (timeout && timeout > 0) {
      const handle = setTimeout(() => {
        _reject(new Error("Element not found: timeout exceeded."));
      }, timeout);
      callback = () => {
        observer.disconnect();
        clearTimeout(handle);
      };
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      for (const mutation of mutations) {
        for (const addedNode of mutation.addedNodes) {
          if (addedNode.matches(selector)) {
            _resolve(addedNode);
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    });

    observer.observe(root, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });
  });
}
```

Example call:

```
await waitForElement("div.bla-bla-bla", {
  timeout: 10000,
  root: document.querySelector("div.some-container") 
});
```

finally note that i trigger click for this element :

```
.tiktok-XXXXXX-DivVideoCardContainer
```

Comment: i have tryed this function but am getting this `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.` here `await waitForElement`. If i do only this function `openAndPrintVideoContent(".tiktok-web-player")` i get the number of comments but only for one video. What i need is to get all videos number of comment and then to sort the video from number of comment.

Answer (score 0):

create video class to store the video informations and at the end sort the results by object property the final code look like this :

```
class Video {
  link;
  title;
  comments;
  element;
  constructor(link, title, comments, element) {
    this.link = link;
    this.title = title;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.element= element;
  }
}

function waitForElm(selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
      return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
    }

    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
        resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });

    observer.observe(document.body, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });
  });
}

function simulateMouseClick(element) {
  // Send mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, click, mouseout
  const eventNames = [
    "mouseover",
    "mouseenter",
    "mousedown",
    "mouseup",
    "click",
    "mouseout",
  ];
  eventNames.forEach((eventName) => {
    const detail = eventName === "mouseover" ? 0 : 1;
    const event = new MouseEvent(eventName, {
      detail: detail,
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    });
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
  });
}

const getVideoInformations = async (videoTriggerElement) => {
  try {
    simulateMouseClick(videoTriggerElement);

    const commentCountElement = await waitForElm(
      '[data-e2e="browse-comment-count"]'
    );

    const descElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-video-desc"]');

    const linkElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-video-link"]');
    const video = new Video(
      linkElement.textContent,
      descElement.children[0].textContent,
      commentCountElement.textContent,
      videoTriggerElement,
    );

    const browserCloseElement = await waitForElm('[data-e2e="browse-close"]');

    simulateMouseClick(browserCloseElement);

    // wait to go back to the video list 
    await waitForElm('[data-e2e="feed-video"]');

    return video;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    return;
  }
};

const getVideoElementList = async () => {
  const videos = document.querySelectorAll('[data-e2e="feed-video"]');
  // console.log(videos)
  return videos;
};

const hydrateVideoElementList = async (videos) => {
  const resources = [];

  for (const video of videos) {
    if(video) {
      const videoInformation = await getVideoInformations(video);
      resources.push(videoInformation);
    }
  }

  return resources;
};
const showSortingElements = (resources) => {
  for (const resource of resources) {
    resource.element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.setAttribute("data-order", resource.comments)
  }

  SortData();
};

function comparator(a, b) {
        if (a.dataset.order< b.dataset.order)
            return -1;
        if (a.dataset.order> b.dataset.order)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
      
    // Function to sort Data
    function SortData() {
        var subjects =
            document.querySelectorAll("[data-order]");
        var subjectsArray = Array.from(subjects);
        let sorted = subjectsArray.sort(comparator);
        sorted.forEach(e =>
            document.querySelector(".tiktok-9fq6q2-DivOneColumnContainer").
                appendChild(e));
    }



const videos = await getVideoElementList();

const resources = await hydrateVideoElementList(videos);

// sorting array of object by property
resources.sort((a, b) => (a.comments > b.comments ? 1 : -1));

showSortingElements(resources);

console.log(resources);
```

note : to get a list of all video i use **'[data-e2e="feed-video"]'** selector because what you are using **".tiktok-18e9va3-DivContainer"** can return only one element

Comment: The `data-e-2="feed-video"` does not exist on the `https://www.tiktok.com/search?q=chatg&t=1689152352319` search results, then i use the div class

Comment: @Maison012 use this data-e2e="search_top-item-list"for top search tab and this data-e2e="search_video-item-list" for videos tab

Comment: should i replace all my funtion with this one you have done here? Cuse when i replace all what i have with this, i get `'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.` here `const videos = await getVideoElementList();      const resources = await hydrateVideoElementList(videos);` i does not understand couse both of these functions are on `async`

Comment: You mean to replace `          sorted.forEach(e => document.querySelector(".tiktok-9fq6q2-DivOneColumnContainer").appendChild(e));
` this attribute here with this ` data-e2e="search_video-item-list"`? @lapwood

Comment: This element does not exist on my search result`data-e2e="search_video-item-list"` where should it exist on single video ? or on searc results video?

Comment: Does you have tested this code? Is working for you? I am playing around all day long with this code but not lucky to make it work. Can you please do a full code for me please?